# How to get condition where date > 24 hours

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, comparison, string-comparison

Let say I have one field resolved.time.
resolved.time="07/06/17 14:19:39"

I would like to write a condition on javascript like this:

```
if resolved.time>24 hours{
print("true");
}
else
{
print("false");
}
```

How can i write this condition "if resolved.time>24 hours" on JS?
Appreciate for anything help.

Thanks and regards,
Okik

Comment: How can a point in time (a date) be "greater than" a period of time? That's like saying "is tomorrow less than The Eighties?" or worse "is an onion longer than all the cheeses?"

Comment: yes i means, greater than a period of field resolved time, means tomorrow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let resolved = {}
resolved.time = "07/06/17 14:19:39"

// convert resolved.time to milliseconds
const time = (new Date(resolved.time)).getTime()

const dayInMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000


// check if duration between now and `time is greater than 24h 
if (Date.now() - time > dayInMs) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

Comment: Please do not recommend parsing strings with the built-in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @RobG I didn't know about `Date.parse()`. Thanks for the tip.